# how to prevent fancybox from deleting the clicked thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Fist time using fancybox and it's not going so well.. starting to wish I didn't bother with it.

I have some thumbnails in a row, fine, then when I click one it opens the THUMBNAIL instead of the link whats worse it DELETES the thumbnail from the DOM. I've dug around in the fancybox src for the issue but there's a lot of it and I'll probably end up killing functionality so I thought I'd post here.

heres the code:

The raw HTML comes from CMS looking like:

```
<img src="http://blah..blah..from..flickr..001_s.jpg" alt="my image one" class="flickr-square" title="test image" longdesc="" data-url="http://blah..blah..flickr..detail..page" data-orig="http://blah..blah..flickr..big..001_b.jpg">
<img src="http://blah..blah..from..flickr..002_s.jpg" alt="my image one" class="flickr-square" title="test image" longdesc="" data-url="http://blah..blah..flickr..detail..page" data-orig="http://blah..blah..flickr..big..002_b.jpg">
```

I then run some stuff in backbone view render, the important bit is this:

```
    var imgs = this.$el.find("img"); //:a jquery group of the img elements above
    this.content = this.$el.find("span.postcontent");
    //empty current
    this.content.empty();
    //make replacement
    for(i= 0;i<imgs.length;i++)
    {

        var curImg = $(imgs[i]);
        var curLink = $("<a/>");
        curLink.attr("href",curImg.attr('data-orig'))
        curLink.append(curImg);
        curLink.on("click",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.fancybox.open(imgs)
        });
        this.content.append(curLink)
    }
```

I now have rendered html like this:

```
   <a href="http://blah..blah..flickr..big..001_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://blah..blah..from..flickr..001_s.jpg" alt="my image one" class="flickr-square" title="test image" longdesc="" data-url="http://blah..blah..flickr..detail..page" data-orig="http://blah..blah..flickr..big..001_b.jpg">
   </a>
   <a href="http://blah..blah..flickr..big..002_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://blah..blah..from..flickr..002_s.jpg" alt="my image one" class="flickr-square" title="test image" longdesc="" data-url="http://blah..blah..flickr..detail..page" data-orig="http://blah..blah..flickr..big..002_b.jpg">
   </a>
```

So far so good... now, when I click the link/thumb it does the fancybox thinggy but shows the THUMBNAIL not the linked image, tiny in the middle in it's lightboxy thing and whats really annoying is that the clicked thumbnail in the page itself has now been completely removed from the dom ie.:

```
       <a href="http://blah..blah..flickr..big..001_b.jpg"> 
         ///THIS IS MISSING COMPLETELY..... ggggggrrrrr 
       </a>
       <a href="http://blah..blah..flickr..big..002_b.jpg">
        <img src="http://blah..blah..from..flickr..002_s.jpg" alt="my image one" class="flickr-square" title="test image" longdesc="" data-url="http://blah..blah..flickr..detail..page" data-orig="http://blah..blah..flickr..big..002_b.jpg">
       </a>
```

Comment: Can the HTML from the CMS not just be in the Fancybox format? i.e. `<a href="big-image.jpg><img src="small-image.jpg"></a>`

Comment: sadly not it's a pre-req for responding to crappy devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering and voting up the previous two because they both helped but were not the definitive answer. The [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) was not clear that if you use only the "group" as a jquery array you must also specify options therefore the correnct answer is to do this (passing two arguments):

```
            $.fancybox.open(imgs,
                {
                    href:this.href,
                    title:curImg.attr("title")
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen Fancybox used like that. Normally, you don't need to trigger `$.fancybox.open` like that. You can just bind `fancybox()` to the `<a>` tags.

HTML:

```
<a href="big-image.jpg" class="fancybox">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg">
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
```

Try just using that function after you've got the DOM to look like that.

[edit]

I couldn't get your DOM manipulation to quite work, but I tested with this fiddle, and it seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/haRnQ/4/

**NOTE:** I didn't import the styles or images for the demo, so it will be unstyled, but it still works.

Comment: yeah, it's a big MVC javascript app which doesnt have any content to begin with so it can't do all of the setup on ready/load etc

Comment: My solution has it, though. If you just manipulate your DOM to look like that, then you need one simple jQuery call. My Fiddle has a sample of it working (takes your HTML and manipulates it to look like my `<a><img></a>` and then just one quick fancybox call). It's a little quirky because the CSS isn't loaded (so it's not registering a close click or anything), but I tested it locally with all the css and images from fancybox and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this

```
$.fancybox.open(imgs)
```

by this

```
$.fancybox({
 href: this.href
});
```

because `imgs` is the collection of your thumbnails (all `<img>` elements), which are moved to fancybox on `click` but not moved back after close.

In any case I would recommend you to add a `class` to `<a>` otherwise any other anchor you may have in your page would try to open fancybox.

Comment: yeah, doing the href way will ignore the 'group' sadly, which means no back/next etc

Answer (score 0):

I believe Fancybox prefers wrapping your images in an anchor. This is important to note as Fancybox **removes** the anchor when activating a slide show to prevent clicking on the anchor when the modal is active.

Calling FB from the thumb behaves like you have experienced by deleting the thumb and not recovering it after the modal is closed.

This is my typical FB setup (not a thumb gallery):

```
<a href="image1.jpg" class="fb" rel="fb1"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<div style="display: none">
    <a href="image2.jpg" class="fb" rel="fb1"></a>
    <a href="image3.jpg" class="fb" rel="fb1"></a>
    ...
</div>
```